# Minimalism in the calendar in the top bar Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, notification, customization, calendar

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and have a small pet-peeve; when one clicks on the calendar on the top bar, it opens the little window with the calendar and notifications. Furthermore, the notifications area is larger then I would prefer, if not just get rid of the area altogether. I am curious if there is a way to modify this window to make the notifications side smaller or gone. UPDATE: The second screenshot is the calendar after using PRATAP's method.

[image: screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that if you reduce the width of this Notification Area, you will not be able to change the media controls like songs - forward, pause, etc. will not be able to see notifications etc.

It depends on the User-Shell Theme you are using..

for example: In Ubuntu 18.04 the default User-Shell Theme is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

open the file and look for the entry `.message-list` and change the width by trail and errors.

see the below GIF..
[image]

Notification Area when the width is 31.5em
[image]

Notification Area when the width is 2px
[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I use a different shell theme but was able to locate the width in the .css file. Thank you!

Comment: @PRATAP Nice hack. Beware that the edit may be overwritten by a future update.

Comment: Hey I want to change it's background color with black. So can you tell me that from where I should change the color ?

Comment: Hi.. not understood exactly.. can you highlight with arrow mark please?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1177603/739431

Answer (score 2):

The extension [Notification Center](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1526/notification-centerselenium-h/) will do what you want. It separates the notifications out to a separate icon on the top bar.

To remove the notifications part of the calendar drop down, you need to disable "Keep Events List besides Calendar" on the notifications tab in the options of the extension.

Everything related to notifications, media control, etc. will now happen under that separate notification button.

Comment: I did not test your method since the method above works well for me, and isn't another extension. But I was unable to find that extension in the official repositories in Ubuntu Software, another reason I did not go with your method. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Glad it worked for you with one of the approaches. No indeed, the extension is not in the repo's. I also found about such edit, but I attempted to locate a way using extensions rather than hard-editing the source code, and found this extension.