# How to change background color of pop out menu of the top bar of Ubuntu 18.04 lockscreen and unlockscreen?

Tags: gnome, gdm

I would like to change the background color of the pop out menu of the Top Bar in the lockscreen and unlockscreen of Ubuntu 18.04 (using GDM). It appears when I clicked the "power, sound, network" button located at the far right end of the top bar. I would like to know the name of the css selector to make this change. I tried this change but nothing happened.

```
/* Popovers/Menus */
.popup-menu {
  min-width: 15em; }
  .popup-menu .popup-sub-menu {
    background-color: yellow; /* changed from #3a3a34 to yellow */
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0px #2c2c28; }
  .popup-menu .popup-menu-content {
    padding: 1em 0em; }
  .popup-menu .popup-menu-item {
    spacing: 12px; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:ltr {
      padding: .4em 1.75em .4em 0em; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:rtl {
      padding: .4em 0em .4em 1.75em; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:checked {
      background-color: #3a3a34;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px #2c2c28;
      font-weight: bold; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item.selected {
      background-color: rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.1);
      color: #eeeeec; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:active {
      background-color: #dd4814;
      color: #ffffff; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:insensitive {
      color: rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.5); }
  .popup-menu .popup-inactive-menu-item {
    color: #eeeeec; }
    .popup-menu .popup-inactive-menu-item:insensitive {
      color: rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.5); }
  .popup-menu.panel-menu {
    -boxpointer-gap: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 1.75em; }
```

What is the correct way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the standard `ubuntu.css` file the below part is what you are looking for. Concentrate on "green" color.

```
.popup-menu-boxpointer,
.candidate-popup-boxpointer {
  -arrow-border-radius: 3px;
  -arrow-background-color: green;
  -arrow-border-width: 1px;
  -arrow-border-color: #1f1f1c;
  -arrow-base: 24px;
  -arrow-rise: 11px;
  -arrow-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black; }
```

[image]

---

Edit: Concentrate on Blue & Yellow colors in below.. Hope you can manage further..

```
/* Popovers/Menus */
.popup-menu {
color: blue;
  min-width: 15em; }
  .popup-menu .popup-sub-menu {
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0px #2c2c28; }
  .popup-menu .popup-menu-content {
    padding: 1em 0em; }
  .popup-menu .popup-menu-item {
    spacing: 12px; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:ltr {
      padding: .4em 1.75em .4em 0em; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:rtl {
      padding: .4em 0em .4em 1.75em; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item:checked {
      background-color: #3a3a34;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px #2c2c28;
      font-weight: bold; }
    .popup-menu .popup-menu-item.selected {
      background-color: rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.1);
      color: yellow; }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Btw, when GNOME-shell user-themes extension is switched on, and a gnome-shell theme (e.g. Arc) is used, the above mentioned changes to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` will only occur in the unlockscreen and the lockscreen, and it will not be carried into the user's desktop theme.

Comment: How do I also change the color of the font and icons in this pop-up menu?

Comment: Font will do for now. I tried adding `color: black;` and `-arrow-color: black;` in there and elsewhere but it did not work.  :(

Comment: Hi, Answer Edited, please have a review..

Comment: Thanks for the directions... I discovered the following... To effect changes to the font and icon in `.popup-menu{}` of **only the lockscreen and unlockscreen and not the desktop**, changes SHOULD NOT me made in `.popup-menu .popup-sub-menu{}`. Instead, these selectors SHOULD be changed: `.popup-menu .popup-menu-item.selected{}`, `.popup-menu .popup-menu-item:active{}`, `.popup-menu .popup-menu-item:insensitive{}`, `.popup-menu .popup-inactive-menu-item{}`, `.popup-menu .popup-inactive-menu-item:insensitive{}`, and .`slider{}`.  ;)