# Change colours in Gnome shell for top dialogs in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes

I took the gnome-shell files from 19.10 and it is working fine on 18.04. Just that it is light coloured. Can I change it to dark ? As you can see in the images below, these elements are the same as in Yaru, they need to be dark in Yaru-dark.

If possible, kindly attend this issue

[image]

[image]

@PRATAP's comment worked. Only that I need to change these icons to White which is dark now once I added the code into yaru-dark>gnome-shell>gnome-shell.css

[image]

I need to fix the notification active unreadable issue too. Also, if possible, remove gradient from top bar and make it plain shade of black. Thanks.

[image]

Sound and Brightness icons and tooltip-popup-menu needs fixing.

Comment: this may help https://askubuntu.com/a/1177608/739431

Comment: @PRATAP , most of it worked, thanks. I have one more thing to do, please check.

Comment: are you using yaru-dark or yaru? based on that I will try for remaining two points of your Q. Thanks!

Comment: Yaru dark. But there is only one gnome-shell.css. I fixed the button issue somehow. I will update the question in a couple of minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @PRATAP Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Icon's theming Can be achieved with below content in your gnome-shell.css file

```
.system-menu-action {
  -st-icon-style: symbolic;
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 32px;
  /* wish we could do 50% */
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #c5cbd0; }
  .system-menu-action:hover, .system-menu-action:focus {
    background-color: green;
    color: #3D3D3D;
    border: none;
    padding: 14px; }
  .system-menu-action:active {
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.2);
    color: #3D3D3D; }
  .system-menu-action > StIcon {
    icon-size: 16px; }
```

[image]

Concentrate on blue, yellow & green lines in above content.

Concentrate on "green" line in below content.

```
.popup-menu-icon {
  color:green;
  icon-size: 1.09em; }
```

[image]

And then follow this post for other two icon colors out of 4 green icons.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1177608/739431

Comment: How to change sound and brightness icon as well ? Thanks.

Comment: I will try and update.

Comment: Yes. Mine is different. Can you share that gnome-shell.css file ? Most other things are fine. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link..  https://we.tl/t-ftPvmz2O2z